# PHP htaccess rewrite URL with parameters while keeping index page

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have been looking for a solution, but can't find one.

The problem is the following:

I have a directory on my website, for example `domain.com/directory/`. I made a custom CMS with custom URL's that are added after `directory/`, like for example `domain.com/directory/example-page`. I used htaccess to rewrite the URL of `directory/post.php?url=xxx` to `directory/xxx`

The problem is that it is not working, since I have an index.php file I want to keep using.

I fixed it by doing it like this:

```
RewriteRule ^directory/subdirectory/(.*)$ directory/post.php?url=$1 [NC,L] [QSA]
```

But I don't want to use the extra subdirectory in the URL.

So, how can I rewrite `directory/post.php?url=xxx` to `directory/xxx` while keeping `directory/` working with index.php?

I know it sounds complicated, but I have been looking for a solution for days.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is your htaccess located in root?

Comment: @starkeen yes it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following rule

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^directory/([^/.]+)/?$ /directory/post.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand the issue correctly, but this should work;

```
RewriteRule    ^directory/?$    /index.php?url=test
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but the problem is I want to see my index.php page when visiting domain.com/directory/ as usual, but I also want to redirect directory/post.php?url=xxx to directory/xxx

Comment: @SenneVandenputte This should work, but you need to add it as an additional rule before the other one. This rule will pass onto index.php if there is nothing after `directory/` and it needs a `[L]` flag to tell it to stop processing further rules. If there is anything after `directory/`, this rule will fail and the next will be processed.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn Thanks, but it's still not really what I'm looking for. I'll give exactly what I'm looking for. `mydomain.com/guides/` contains a section of my website with guides and info on a specific topic. When visiting this URL, you are shown the index page, which is normal. There are also other files like `guides/buying-guides` and `guides/training-guides`, all rewritten to remove .php. Now, I have a post.php which uses parameters to be rewritten. So I need `domain.com/guides/post.php?url=example` to become `domain.com/guides/example`, while keeping my other files reachable as well.